# Use link words in a text in UITextView [Objective-C, Xcode]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, hyperlink, uitextview

I`m starting in Objective-c this Year and I found nothing that could help me in the logic of how elaborate it:

Look!

I have a UITableView with a list of drugs. When I click on any medication, I'm taken to a DetailViewController that displays the text information about this drug. In this text, I want every time a drug name appear, it appears as if it were a “link”. So when the user clicks, it will be taken to other remedy detailviewcontroller without need to go back to the list of remedies! What is the better way to implement this?

I thought about passing an array with all drugs for DetailTableView controller via Segue, and then conduct a search for any of the remedies present in the text, but i don't know how to turn that word into a link, or set a function to become part of the text (the drug name) clickable

Just to make it clear, let's assume that we are reading the details of the text on the drug called Amoxicillin:

“Amoxicillin drug works better than erythromycin”

What I want is that the name Erythromycin become some kind of link, so when the user clicks on it, is brought to the screen details about erythromycin. Do you  guys understand what i mean?

P.S.: I saw that the UITextView has an option called "Links" in attribute inspector, but i have no idea how to use it or if this is for what i want

Thank you all again!!

Answer (score 0):

Use UITextView And select these attribute.

[image: img]

Comment: Yeah, i saw that, but how i implement the function to open the detailViewController when i click in a word? how i transform a word in a clickable link to another view controller? That`s the real question. But thank you anyway, your help is really welcome!